# Why does $f(-x+a)$ shift to the right?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x+a)$ ($a>0$) represents a shift of $f(x)$ by $a$ units to the *left* , but $f(-x+a)$ represents a shift of $f(-x)$ to the *right* by $a$ units. Can someone explain to me why this happens? I thought that $f(-x+a) = f(-(x-a))$ (that is, shift $f(x)$ $a$ units to the right, and then reflect in the $y$-axis), but this is clearly incorrect, too.
I have a feeling that this has an obvious explanation, but I cannot see it. All help appreciated.

Comment: [Explaining transformations 'inside' a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4306919/21813)

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have $g(x)=f(-x)$, then $f(-x+a) = g(x-a)$.
2. the graph of $g(x-a)$ is the graph of $g(x)$, shifted to the *right* by $a$.

So there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

It's shifting to the right because even if you have FIRST translated to the left by $a$ unit, THEN you reflect on the y-axis (because of the (-1) factor of x). so the LEFT translation becomes a RIGHT translation, due to this reflection.

For example:

$f(x + a)$ :  You are translating to the left (by $a$ units).

$f(-x + a)$ : You are translating to the left (by $a$ units), THEN, reflecting it. The result is indeed a RIGHT translation.

[image: example]

Comment: (+1) for answer. Note, the over **outlook** may not be the same for odd functions.

Comment: Is it useful to think about the order of operations inside the parens being performed from right to left, then?

Comment: "right to left" is a bit unprecise since you could have "f(a-x)", which is the same as "f(-x+a)"... I don't know what is the correct math name, but I like to think it is like "reversing the operation": To get "-x + a", you need first multiply by (-1) then, add "a". The transformation does that in reverse: translating (adding "a"), then inverting (multiply by (-1) ).